# FileProvider not working

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is to get a file that is in the private area to be opened by another program. In this example, a image viewer app.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.myapp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/path" />
    </provider>
```

/res/xml/path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="cache" path="cache/"/>
</paths>
```

Java code (file location)

```
File file = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + File.separator + "cache" + File.separator + filename);
```

Java code (open file)

```
    if(file != null && file.isFile() && file.canRead() && file.length() > 0){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(file.toURI().toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < resInfoList.size(); i++) {
            try{
                ResolveInfo resolveInfo = resInfoList.get(i);
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }catch(Exception e){

            }catch(Error e){

            }
        }

        MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(".jpg");
        newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
        newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        try {
            context.startActivity(newIntent);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

This always results in a toast message "Unable to find item". What am I doing wrong and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong

```
File file = new File(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + File.separator + "cache" + File.separator + filename);
```

Use `getCacheDir()` to get the cache directory, as your approach is not going to be reliable for secondary accounts on Android 4.2+ tablets and Android 5.0+ phones. So, this should be:

```
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
```

Then, you need to replace `Uri.fromFile(file)` with a call to `getUriForFile()` on `FileProvider`, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#GetUri). What you presently have is a `Uri` pointing to a file, not pointing to a `ContentProvider`, let alone your `FileProvider` implementation.

Finally, you will need to call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent` before you use it with `startActivity()`, as otherwise the app that responds to the `startActivity()` request will not have access to the content.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrates a working implementation of a `FileProvider`.